# Python sqlite3 db: Structuring database properly. Skip first column when writing to db. Avoid columns with 1-cell data only

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a python script that writes data to sqlite3 Database. It has 26 columns, but 15 of those columns only need 1 cell data.

Instead of having 15 columns each having 1 cell of data I would like to gather them into a single (or two) columns only. I don't know how to do that with Sqlite3. I was thinking maybe loop-print all the settings into the first one or two columns, and then from there when writing to the database tell sqlite3 to ignore/skip the first few columns. Is that possible?

Later on I load database into db browser for sqlite and export to csv and then load them into excel/google doc. I was hoping to avoid having to do a lot of copy/paste after importing to excel/google doc by structuring it properly from the beginning.

**Current database**

```
| 1| Time      | Type  | Price    | Amount  | Gain     | Market    | Option 1 | Acc     | Setting a | Setting b  |
| 2|-----------|-------|----------|---------|----------|-----------|----------|---------|-----------|------------|
| 3| 22:12:15  | Buy   | 660.33   | 0.0130  | 8.58429  | Market 1  | 0.00085  | DD_23   | 0.00233   |     5      |
| 4| 22:12:15  | Sell  | 659.58   | 0.0070  | 4.61706  |           |          |         |           |            |
| 5| 19:36:08  | Buy   | 670.00   | 0.0082  | 5.49400  |           |          |         |           |            |
| 6| 19:36:08  | Sell  | 670.33   | 0.0058  | 3.88791  |           |          |         |           |            |
| 7| 19:36:08  | Buy   | 671.23   | 0.0060  | 4.02738  |           |          |         |           |            |
| 8| 13:01:41  | Sell  | 667.15   | 0.0015  | 1.00073  |           |          |         |           |            |
| 9| 13:01:41  | Buy   | 667.10   | 0.0185  | 12.3414  |           |          |         |           |            |
|10| 07:14:36  | Sell  | 657.55   | 0.0107  | 7.03579  |           |          |         |           |            |
|11| 07:14:36  | Buy   | 657.08   | 0.0005  | 0.32854  |           |          |         |           |            |
|12| 07:14:36  | Sell  | 656.59   | 0.0088  | 5.77799  |           |          |         |           |            |
```

**Desired solution 1: Single column solution**

```
| 1| Script info | Time      | Type  | Price    | Amount  | Gain     |
| 2|-------------|-----------|-------|----------|---------|----------|
| 3| Market      | 22:12:15  | Buy   | 660.33   | 0.0130  | 8.58429  |
| 4| Market 1    | 22:12:15  | Sell  | 659.58   | 0.0070  | 4.61706  |
| 5| Option 1    | 19:36:08  | Buy   | 670.00   | 0.0082  | 5.49400  |
| 6| 0.00085     | 19:36:08  | Sell  | 670.33   | 0.0058  | 3.88791  |
| 7| Acc         | 19:36:08  | Buy   | 671.23   | 0.0060  | 4.02738  |
| 8| DD_23       | 13:01:41  | Sell  | 667.15   | 0.0015  | 1.00073  |
| 9| Setting a   | 13:01:41  | Buy   | 667.10   | 0.0185  | 12.3414  |
|10| 0.00233     | 07:14:36  | Sell  | 657.55   | 0.0107  | 7.03579  |
|11| Setting b   | 07:14:36  | Buy   | 657.08   | 0.0005  | 0.32854  |
|12| 5           | 07:14:36  | Sell  | 656.59   | 0.0088  | 5.77799  |
```

**Desired solution 2: Double column solution**

```
| 1| Script info | Script settings | Time      | Type  | Price    | Amount  | Gain     |
| 2|-------------|-----------------|-----------|-------|----------|---------|----------|
| 3| Market      | Market 1        | 22:12:15  | Buy   | 660.33   | 0.0130  | 8.58429  |
| 4| Option 1    | 0.00085         | 22:12:15  | Sell  | 659.58   | 0.0070  | 4.61706  |
| 5| Acc         | DD_23           | 19:36:08  | Buy   | 670.00   | 0.0082  | 5.49400  |
| 6| Setting a   | 0.00233         | 19:36:08  | Sell  | 670.33   | 0.0058  | 3.88791  |
| 7| Setting b   | 5               | 19:36:08  | Buy   | 671.23   | 0.0060  | 4.02738  |
| 8|             |                 | 13:01:41  | Sell  | 667.15   | 0.0015  | 1.00073  |
| 9|             |                 | 13:01:41  | Buy   | 667.10   | 0.0185  | 12.3414  |
|10|             |                 | 07:14:36  | Sell  | 657.55   | 0.0107  | 7.03579  |
|11|             |                 | 07:14:36  | Buy   | 657.08   | 0.0005  | 0.32854  |
|12|             |                 | 07:14:36  | Sell  | 656.59   | 0.0088  | 5.77799  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** [to explore the idea mentioned in the comments]:

Instead of having 15 columns/values to describe the selection group perhaps you could:

- Create a string in python do describe the selection group. Something like "Setting 1: value 1, Setting 2: value 2,.......Setting 15: value15"
- Replace the 15 columns with one TEXT column
- Insert the text for every row in the selection group.

---

---

I'm not sure what problem you are trying to solve. This

> ... I load database into db browser for sqlite and export to csv and then
>   load them into excel/google doc.

indicates to me that it's a manual process.

This

> when writing to the database tell sqlite3 to ignore/skip the first few
>   columns.

indicates to me that you only want these columns in the export.

> `Time      | Type  | Price    | Amount  | Gain`

Couldn't you write a query `SELECT time,type,price,amount,gain from thetable` then choose "Export to CSV" from the little icon to right of the results panel?

Or maybe easier, if you are going to discard the "1-cell data", don't load them in the first place. Or load them into a different table (on the python side).

Or perhaps I don't understand the problem :)

Comment: I want to run the same script, but with two different settings. Then afterwards I want to compare results of script when running with setting x to result of script when running with setting y. I need a way to store the "settings" data in the database otherwise I have no way of knowing which results come from which setting.
My thinking when "wanting to ignore the first few columns" is that I can then print the settings to those first columns right when the script starts, so they are safely stored. But only if next writing to database doesn't overwrite it.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid, if I run 20 different settings, to have to manually copy/paste 1-cell columns 15,16,17,18,19 etc. and turn them into 1 column, for each of the 20 different databases

Comment: Have you considered : instead of 15 1-cell columns, make 1 text column that describes the "script info" and update it into each row? Something like "Market: Market1, Option: 0.0085,........"

Comment: Yeah that was one of my first solutions I tried, but if script only ran for say 10 rows, you'd miss the data from the last 5 so decided against it.
Maybe this just is a google sheet task rather than a sqlite3 problem.

Comment: That's a good idea. With the use of google sheets "text wrapper" (so text makes new line when reaching end of cell) option I do as you suggest and still keep the all the settings visible. Thank you very much for taking the time to help, much appreciated :)